# What mathematical formula could be used to compare a value with an interval?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following $x$-values:

> $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$

If the value $3$ is given, with its two neighbouring numbers, the numbers are displayed as follows:

> $1$, $2$, $\color {red} {3}$, $4$, $5$

But what if the numbers 'wrap around'? For example, if the value $6$ is given, with its two neighbouring numbers, the numbers are displayed as follows:

> $4$, $5$, $\color {red} {6}$, $7$, $0$

What formula could be used for such a task?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, choose the tags carefully, this is not a question of linear algebra.

Comment: I would approach this with thinking in modulus 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $n$ and its neighbors would be:
$(n-2)\bmod 8, (n-1)\bmod 8, n, (n+1)\bmod 8, (n+2)\bmod 8$.

Here, the operation $n \bmod m$ is defined as $$n\bmod m = n-m \lfloor n/m \rfloor$$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!